# How to fix an Electron app that crashes when installing PDFJS?

Tags: node.js, electron, pdf.js, electron-forge, pdfjs-dist

I have an Electron app that uses `pdfjs-dist`. On Mac OSX, the app was working perfectly. But I had to use a new computer with OSX Ventura 13.4.1.

When simply installing `pdfjs-dist`, not even importing nor using it, the app can't compile and crashes immediately. The error is:

```js
› Package 'gobject-2.0' requires 'libffi >= 3.0.0' but version of libffi is 2.1
  Package 'gobject-2.0' requires 'libffi >= 3.0.0' but version of libffi is 2.1
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/canvas-postbuild.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/backend/Backend.o
  In file included from ../src/backend/Backend.cc:1:
  ../src/backend/Backend.h:3:10: fatal error: 'cairo.h' file not found
  #include <cairo.h>
  ^~~~~~~~~
  1 error generated.
  make: *** [Release/obj.target/canvas/src/backend/Backend.o] Error 1
  Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
  at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.j…
  at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
  at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
Error: node-gyp failed to rebuild '/Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/canvas'
at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/myname/Desktop/myapp/node_modules/@electron/rebuild/lib/module-type/node-gyp/node-gyp.js:118:24)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```

I have browsed github issues, and I have installed every related packages that might be needed with brew: `pkg-config`, `cairo`, `pango`, `libpng`, `jpeg`, `giflib`, `librsvg`, `libffi`. The computer has Node `18.16.1`.

Configuration:

- Operating system and its version: `OSX 13.4.1 (Ventura)`
- PDF.js version: `3.8.162`

The crash happens when simply installing `pdfjs-dist`, so the issue definitely comes from here. Also, `canvas` is marked as an `optionalDependencies`of `pdfjs-dist`. Maybe I need to install an additional package?

Thank you!